# I can only get the values from a form if I change them

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this form:

```
<div class="form-group modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="mediadorForm" #form>
      <input type="hidden" name="angcod" id="angcod" formControlName="angcod" class="form-control" [(value)]="mediador.angcod" #angcod>
      <input type="text" name="angnom" id="angnom" formControlName="angnom" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del mediador" [(value)]="mediador.angnom" #angnom required>
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-5 pt-1">Factura comisiones</div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <select class="form-control" name="angfac" id="angfac" formControlName="angfac" #angfac>
            <option [(value)]="sn.desres" *ngFor="let sn of sino" [selected]="sn.desres === mediador.angfac">{{ sn.desnom }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="enviaForm(mediadorForm); editMediadorModal.close();">- Guardar cambios -</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="editMediadorModal.close();">Cancelar</button>
  </div>
```

And then this on the component:

```
export class MediadorComponent implements DoCheck, OnInit {

  mediadorForm: FormGroup;
  mediador: Mediador;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mediadorForm = this.fb.group({
      angcod: '',
      angnom: '',
      angfac: ''
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.mediador = this.mediadorService.mediador;
  }

  enviaForm(form: any) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

the form loads into the fields its values but if I send it, console log outputs

```
Object { angcod: "", angnom: "", angfac: "" }
```

if I don't change nothing. If I change the value of angnom from "John Doe" to "Barak Obama", it outputs:

```
Object { angcod: "", angnom: "Barak Obama", angfac: "" }
```

but the unchanged values are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove this [(value)] attribute from all fields. I think it will work

Comment: can you tell what data is being loaded into the form fields?

Comment: Most probably removing [(value)] should work as suggested by @TheParam

Comment: @TheParam @Utkarsh If I remove the [(value)] attribute the form doesn't get the values from `mediador` to edit.

Comment: @Utkarsh the data being loaded is `mediador: Mediador;`, which is defined by the model:

`export class Mediador {
  angcod: string;
  angnom: string;
  angfac: string;
}`

The data is loaded correctly into the form fields.

Comment: instead of using [(value)], assign those values while building the form . like : `
   `this.mediadorForm = this.fb.group({
      angcod: 'mediador.angcod',
      angnom: 'mediador.angnom',
      angfac: 'mediador.angfac'
    });`

Comment: @Utkarsh I think it has worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to assign the values to the Form will be

```
    this.mediadorForm = this.fb.group({ angcod: 'mediador.angcod', 
angnom: 'mediador.angnom', 
angfac: 'mediador.angfac' });
```